# In the sequence where Kazuo plays for Aihara, are both panels with a shifted style references to works of art?

Tags: shindo

At the end of chapter 19 of *Shindo*, Kazuo Kikuna plays the piano for Kozue Aihara, his piano studio classmate, after their date. Uta Naruse listens as she passes Kazuo's house, and in two of the panels, she is drawn against a background with a markedly different art style:

[image: first panel]

[image: second panel]

The second panel clearly contains a reference to [Gustav Klimt's *The Kiss*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kiss_(Klimt)). With this in mind, is the first panel also a reference to a work of art? I tried looking at some other Klimt paintings to look for a similar image, but I couldn't find anything overly convincing, perhaps partly because I don't have a strong visual arts background.